# Wireshark - Facebook Account

Tags: password, wireshark

Someone use Wireshark software, if he browse on the internet from home (using the same router) and I'm also at home, is he able to find the password of my Facebook account? I think I'm using the TCP protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most, if not all traffic to facebook, is over https. So even if the listener observed your traffic, it's encrypted.

You said you only share a router. If they run wireshark (etc) on the router itself, then they could potentially get the encrypted traffic. But it sounds like the other is on another networked computer - in which case your network traffic should not be visible to them, unless you're both on a Hub, which would be pretty hilarious since those went out of style in the 90s.

In every general sense, your data is secure. If the other guy works for the NSAKGB, then you're probably screwed.

Comment: Yes, he works for NSA for real. Why do you think I'm screwed

Comment: I mostly make constant jokes about the NSA. You're not necessarily screwed, but I think the NSA has broken RSA encryption, if true, then https encrypted traffic isn't safe. What's the router your share? Make & Model?

Comment: It is a Linksys 1900ac

Comment: If my account would be a http website, am I protected?

Comment: Logging in to anything where the username & password are not sent over https (so http instead) is very sketchy and should be avoided quite aggressively.

Comment: Does your friend have full physical access to that router?

Comment: Yes, he does have access

Comment: The claims about NSA having broken RSA (with shorter key sizes) all mention that it still requires a huge amount of computational resources to crack a particular RSA key as opposed to an infeasibly huge amount of computational resources. Unless the NSA views you as a priority target they won't try that against you.

Comment: Yeah, you have to be a worthy target, I suspect. Anyway, with physical access to the router, you must assume he's got full control of it, so with that your encrypted traffic could be logged. But decrypting it is typically a matter of great motivation.